# Use system(" cls ") without Shuttering on Pacman Game

Tags: c++

I've been working on Pacman Game Development on Dev C++  . I use Looping and system("cls") to Re-Drawing the entire updated map when the player moving and this works , but it causes shuttering each time player pressing the button ( Arrow Key ) . So if you guys have any Idea so I cant only updated the player "character" only without redrawing the whole map? or any code can make the system("cls") works faster without causing shuttering? . Thanks I really appriciate your help :D

```
int main()
{

    char map[31][65] = 
    {  
       "                                                              " ,
       " @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ " ,
       " @                                                          @ " ,
       " @                                                          @ " ,
       " @                                                          @ " ,
       " @                                                          @ " ,
       " @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@       C                               @ " ,
       " @                                                          @ " ,
       " @                                                          @ " ,
       " @                                                          @ " ,
       " @               @@@@@@@@@@@@@@                             @ " ,
       " @               @                                          @ " ,
       " @               @                                          @ " ,
       " @               @                       @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @ " ,
       " @               @                                          @ " ,
       " @               @                                          @ " ,
       " @               @                                          @ " ,
       " @      @@@@@@@@@@                                          @ " ,
       " @                                                          @ " ,
       " @                                @                         @ " ,
       " @                                @                         @ " ,
       " @                                @                         @ " ,
       " @                                @                         @ " ,
       " @                                @@@@@@@@@                 @ " ,
       " @                                        @                 @ " ,
       " @                                        @                 @ " ,
       " @                                        @                 @ " ,
       " @                         X              @                 @ " ,                     //  Position Of Character 'X' = map[27][27]
       " @                                        @                 @ " ,
       " @                                                          @ " ,
       " @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ " 

    } ;



    for ( int y = 1 ; y < 31 ; y++ )
    {
        for ( int x = 1 ; x < 65 ; x ++  )
        {
            cout << map[y][x] ;
        }
        cout << endl ;
    }
        cout << map[27][27] ;

    int a = 27 , b = 27 ;
    int c = 0 ;                                                                        // Define What Arrow Key Used to Control The Charater
    while (1)
    {
        c = 0 ;

    switch ( ( c=getch() ) )
    {
        case  KEY_UP : if  ( map[a-1][b] != '@' )
                       {
                         map[a][b] = ' ' ;
                         cout << map[a][b] ;
                         a-- ;
                         map[a][b] = 'X' ;
                         cout << map[a][b] ;
                       }


        break ; 

        case KEY_DOWN : if  ( map[a+1][b] != '@' )
                       {
                         map[a][b] = ' ' ;
                         a++ ;
                         map[a][b] = 'X' ;
                       }
        break ;

        case KEY_LEFT : if  ( map[a][b-1] != '@' )
                       {
                         map[a][b] = ' ' ;
                         b-- ;
                         map[a][b] = 'X' ;
                       }
        break ;

        case KEY_RIGHT : if  ( map[a][b+1] != '@' )
                       {
                         map[a][b] = ' ' ;
                         b++ ;
                         map[a][b] = 'X' ;
                       }
        break ;


    }
     system("cls") ;

        for ( int y = 1 ; y < 31 ; y++ )
    {
        for ( int x = 1 ; x < 65 ; x ++  )
        {
            cout << map[y][x] ;
        }
        cout << endl ;
    }

    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the API you're using have some kind of locate and print? Rather like, dare I say it, the old Turbo C++ interface to DOS?

Comment: @Bathsheba We do not speak its name.

Comment: Im actually  only begginner , I do not understand what do you mean by Turbo C++ interface to DOS?

Comment: You could look at using `ncurses`. http://www.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~hughm/os/notes/ncurses.html.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code <- these work on many systems and have a set cursor position command

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows you can use the [windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutputcharacter) to update the character

```
//Return the handle to the console
GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

//Get the current buffer of the console
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( h, &info );

//Write on the console buffer
BOOL WINAPI WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(
  _In_  HANDLE  hConsoleOutput,
  _In_  LPCTSTR lpCharacter,
  _In_  DWORD   nLength,
  _In_  COORD   dwWriteCoord,
  _Out_ LPDWORD lpNumberOfCharsWritten
);
```

UPDATE:
This is a minimal example to show you how to use the API in windows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    //Handle to standard output console
    HANDLE g_console_handle;
    //Console informations
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO g_console_info;
    //return
    DWORD ret;
    //get handle to console
    g_console_handle = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( g_console_handle, &g_console_info );
    //Get console size
    int rows = g_console_info.dwSize.Y;
    int cols = g_console_info.dwSize.X;
    //Create buffer
    std::vector<char> g_buffer = std::vector<char>( rows *cols, ' ' );
    //console coordinate
    COORD origin;
    //Start writing char from first cell
    origin.X = 0;
    origin.Y = 0;
    //Fill console with tilda
    int t, ti;
    for (t =0;t<rows;t++)
    {
        for (ti =0;ti<cols;ti++)
        {
            g_buffer[t*cols+ti] = '~';
        }
    }

    //Windows API to access the console buffer
    WriteConsoleOutputCharacter
    (
        g_console_handle,       //handle to console
        &g_buffer[0],           //pointer to buffer
        rows*cols,              //number of char to write
        origin,                 //coordinate where start writing
        &ret                    //return number of char actually written
    );

}
```

UPDATE3: Apparently i didn't know how system() work. Look up other answers for that.

Comment: `cls` outputs exactly one character, and it is a clear-screen command, not a space. It is `system()` that is slow, because it has to execute a separate process.

Comment: Still wrong. `cls` does not execute a DOS command. It is `system()` that executes a process, as I already stated. You could output the single character that `cls` outputs and save yourself all this code.

Comment: And if you don't know how something works, don't just post guesswork here.

Comment: You are right. I thought I knew but I was wrong. I'll let more experienced people talk about system() and focus on the part I'm sure about. Thanks for letting me know.